# How to read certain lines of a txt file in java?

Tags: java, file, file-handling, readfile

I want to read only the parts i need to. For example my text file look likes these

```
Name     Age   Gender
=====================
Donald    13    Male
John      14    Non-binary
Pooh      42    Female
```

I only want to read the data but i don't know how because my code reads a .txt file line by line

```
    try {
            File myObj = new File("database.txt");
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) { //to read each line of the file
                String data = myReader.nextLine();
                String [] array = data.split(" "); //store the words in the file line by line
                if(array.length ==5){ // to check if data has all five parameter 
                    people.add(new Person(array[0], array[1],array[2], Double.parseDouble(array[3]), Double.parseDouble(array[4]))); 
                }
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Read File","Javank",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            myReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve ? ignorer first 2 lines ?

Comment: You might want to change your sample file to a less problematic one. "Gay" is not a gender. Using "favorite color" with values of red, green and blue would be rather less distracting...

Comment: `try (var lines = Files.lines(Path.of("database.txt"))) { persons.addAll(lines.skip(2).map(l -> l.split(" ")).filter(a -> a.length == 5).map(a -> new Person(a[0], a[1], a[2], Double.parseDouble(a[3]), Double.parseDouble(a[4]))).collect(Collectors.toList())); }`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call `myReader.nextLine()` twice before entering your loop to ignore the first two lines.

Another approach you can take is to use a `RandomAccessFile` object instead of a `Scanner` to process your input. If you know how many characters are in the file before the beginning of your relevant data, you can use the `RandomAccessFile` object's `seek` method to skip to the beginning of your input, e.g. if there are 50 characters in the file before your data you can use `randomAccessFile.seek(50)` and then read the lines with `randomAccessFile.readLine()`.

I would probably recommend using the first method of skipping 2 lines however because it seems more simple and robust.